# Performance Testing, Inserting batch of records, many insert queries, 20 insert/update in all, Is cursor, while loop, or transaction better

Tags: sql

I'm synchronizing our crm and erp. I'll have a batch hundreds of records from our crm to insert every 15 minutes, into our erp about 20 tables each. I want to insert one record at at time and log any errors if a insert fails on any of the 20 tables and reverse the insert for that record. I can see how to insert one record at a time with a cursor, or while loop. How would I insert one record at a time and log errors using transactions?

--Transaction method
--BEGIN TRANS

--partial code list of cursor method, that is working

```
declare @cur cursor;
declare @x nvarchar(9);
begin
    set @cur = cursor for
    select people_id from powercampustest.dbo.PeopleChanges where (processed is null)

    open @cur
    fetch next from @cur
    into @x

    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    begin
        /* add the rest here */
        begin try
        --20 insert queries


        end try

        begin catch
            --transaction method
            --ROLLBACK

            print 'Error on people id ' + @x

            --cursor method
            --if one insert fails delete all inserted
            --do we want error out on first fail, or try all and report if each failed or not
            --TableListForDelete, list of tables for delete
            --write error in log table
        end catch
        fetch next from @cur
        into @x
    end;

    close @cur;
    deallocate @cur;
end;


===========================================================
--partial code list of while method

select @loop = @@rowcount
if @loop <= 0 Return

Set @PersonId = 0
Select @PersonId =
        (Select Min([PersonId]) From inserted Where [PersonId] > @PersonId)

While @PersonId Is Not Null
    begin
        SELECT ...

    --Get Next Id
    Select @PersonId = 
            (Select Min( [PersonId] ) From inserted Where [PersonId] > @PersonId)

END


    if @@error <> 0
    begin
        raiserror( 1944115471, 16, 65, @MessageType ) with nowait;
        rollback tran;
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
set xact_abort on;
begin tran
    --all your inserts here
commit tran
```

it will do everything if there is no error or nothing if there is one.
  Cursors are evil, do not use them. Loops are not needed for this as well.

Comment: I want to try each insert so I can see all of the errors. Now it takes to long to discover one error at a time. Also, I think if I use a cursor and can step through in debugger a see what is going on in memory. Is there a way to see that in a transaction?